# Handling prop that may or may not contain HTML

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple presentational component that displays text inside a nicely designed box i.e. bunch of DIV's. My component expects three props: `header`, `displayText` and `isHtml`.

Sometimes, I need to pass to my `displayText` prop simple text and other times something that contains HTML such as a hyperlink.

For example, I may pass `Hello World!` or `<a href="http://www.google.com">Click for Google</a>` to the `displayText` prop. Whenever I pass HTML to `displayText`, `isHtml` is set to `TRUE`.

The problem I'm having is that the `PropType` is set to `string` for `displayText` but if I send text with HTML tags, it becomes an `object` and I get an error saying the prop received an `object` but was expecting `string`.

How do I handle this scneario?

My component looks like this:

```
const MyComponent = ({ header, displayText, isHtml }) => {

    const renderHtml = () => {

        return { __html: displayText }
    }

    return (
        <div className="my-fancy-classes">
            <span className="some-more-fancy-classes">{header}</span>
            {isHtml
                ? <div className="some-class" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={renderHtml()} />
                : <div className="some-class">{displayText}</div>
            }
        </div>
    );
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {

    header: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    displayText: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    isHtml: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};
```

Here's what my component declaration looks like inside the parent `JSX` component IF sending HTML:

```
getMyText() {

   let displayText = "";
   if(this.props.isHtml)
      displayText = '<a href="http://www.google.com">Click for Google</a>';

   return displayText;
}

...
<div>
   <MyComponent header="Title" displayText={this.getMyText()} isHtml={true} />
</div>
```

If I'm sending simple text, it will look like this:

```
<div>
   <MyComponent header="Title" displayText={this.props.someProp} isHtml={false} />
</div>
```

Comment: are you sending HTML or JSX ? I believe you are sending JSX tags in displayText instead of HTML.

Comment: I added a section to the bottom of original post. Please see how I send the data to my component. So, I think you're saying I'm sending JSX, not HTML. Whenever I need to send HTML, I will always call a function like `getMyText()` as in my example. If I'm sending simple text, I simply do something like `displayText={this.props.someProp}`. So, not sure how to handle this.

Comment: What is the shape of the object? The object when it is html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html you should use `PropTypes.node` for anything that can be rendered:

> // Anything that can be rendered: numbers, strings, elements or an array
>    // (or fragment) containing these types.
>    optionalNode: PropTypes.node,

so you would have

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  header: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  displayText: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  isHtml: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};
```

You could also use `oneOfType` if you want to have multiple types of PropTypes in one prop

---

**edit**

Also it looks like you might not even need to do `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, etc, if you just return the JSX directly:

```
getMyText() {
  let displayText = "";
  if (this.props.isHtml)
    // Remove quotes around html
    displayText = <a href="http://www.google.com">Click for Google</a>;

  return displayText;
}
```

-

```
const MyComponent = ({ header, displayText, isHtml }) => {
  return (
    <div className="my-fancy-classes">
      <span className="some-more-fancy-classes">{header}</span>
      <div className="some-class">{displayText}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried `PropTypes.node` but still getting an error message. The error reads: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `displayText` supplied to `MyComponent`, expected a ReactNode. And it renders it as `[object Object]`

Comment: I've also tried the `oneOfType` which eliminated the error but it's not rendering the HTML at all. It's still displaying `[object Object]`

Comment: I edited my answer, please take a look -- If I'm understanding correctly, you might be able to remove some of the code to get it working.

Comment: You're right! Using `PropTypes.node` and removing the double quotes in the `getMyText()` function works very nicely. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined your displayText prop to be of type string, it won't work for html objects. You need to define it like this.

```
displayText: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
```

Here any will let you pass any type of content in the displayText prop.